# How to identify, if a person is talking about himself or others in a sentence

Tags: nlp, opennlp, stanford-nlp

I am new to NLP. I want to identify from a sentence, whether the person is talking about himself or others. Can anyone suggest a way to do so?

I am thinking that based on personal pronouns in sentence we can say if the person is talking about himself or others.

I am looking for ways to identify if the person is talking about himself or others, by using POS tagging or a syntactic parser etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO, you're talking about Coreference Resolution system which links multiple mentions of an entity in a document together.

take at look at this [blog](http://blog.dpdearing.com/2012/11/making-coreference-resolution-with-opennlp-1-5-0-your-bitch/) which is about coreference Resolution in OpenNLP.

Here's the OpenNLP [Documentation](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.6.0/manual/opennlp.html#tools.coref)

hope this helps.